# Zurb Foundation Switch for Rails Form Boolean

Tags: ruby-on-rails, switch-statement, boolean, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Still haven't quite got this..
trying to utilize one of these basic switches from
http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/v/5.5.3/components/switch.html

to trigger a true/false for a boolean column in a rails form when submitted.
Guessing it needs JS with 2 ids, but haven't seen any documentation anywhere about it.

Thanks ahead of time!

Comment: It would help if you told us what isn't working. Also you should post what you have tried. Additionally, not sure why you think you need JS – that page you linked to specifically says you do not need it.

Comment: It submits nothing. e.g. boolean column named ldap_enabled.

Comment: the disclaimer did say no JS required,but then in the zurb forums one person said to try something like..

Comment: The switches are checkboxes that have attributes you can use - checked

 

function check() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = true;
}

function uncheck() {
    document.getElementById("myCheck").checked = false;
}

Comment: 113        <%=f.label :admin  %>
  114          <input class="switch-input" id="admin" type="checkbox" name="admin">
  115             <label class="switch-paddle" for="admin">
  116                <%#option value="true" id=admin_true>True</option%>
  117                    <%#option value="false" id=admin_false>False</option%>
  118               <span class="show-for-sr">admin</span>
  119             </div>
  120

Comment: i tried the exact zurb foundation html, which didn't even render correctly, then this...